# Python- Get cookies of a website saved in a browser (Chrome/FireFox)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome

I can manually see the cookies set in the browser.

How can I fetch the cookie from a Python script?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404771/python-get-cookiesof-a-website-saved-in-a-browser-chrome-firefox")
res.cookies
print(res.cookies.keys())
print(res.cookies["prov"])
```

I hope I read your question right.

You may want to ask "how do I read cookies already stored in my browser?". Which I don't think you can do. But Selenium would give you access to a new browser session with which you can obtain more cookies.

### UPDATE

Thanks to Sraw for the pointer, I've tried this now but it wouldn't transfer my login to the requests API. So maybe it is not possible on modern sites, or the OP could try these tools since their question is clearer in their mind than ours.

```
import requests
import browsercookie
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404771/python-get-cookiesof-a-website-saved-in-a-browser-chrome-firefox"
res=requests.get(url)
cj = browsercookie.chrome()
res2 = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
import re
get_title = lambda html: re.findall('(.*?)', html, flags=re.DOTALL)[0].strip()
get_me = lambda html: re.findall('John', html, flags=re.DOTALL)
# At this point I had deleted my answer so this got nothing
# now my answer is reinstated it will return me but not in place of the login button.
print(len(get_me(res2.text)))
```

Comment: I will login to the site first,then i can find the cookie...Now I want to login from python without any login credentials ,but with the cookie, So I want to get the cookie from the browser where i have signed in.? What to do now?

Comment: You definitely can get cookies from browser, it is nothing more than reading a sqlite database. And there is an existing lib: https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/browsercookie/